# Some imported footage has poor contrast and saturation

Tags: video-sequence-editor, import, video

### In short

I have some footage directly from my camera (.mov videos) which looks just fine after importing it into Blender. But other videos and images have noticeably reduced contrast and saturation in blender compared to viewing them with other programs.

### Long version

I was editing a video in blender when I had to add face blur to a video clip. So I did that in a different file, exported the result and reimported it into my editing file. Since there the original clip merges into the edited version, a drastic difference in contrast and saturation is undeniable. This is apparent in the viewport and in renders.
I tried different exports of the edited clip including JPG, PNG and avi wihtout any visible change. However, since the export looks just like the original video with VLC or Windows' image viewer, I don't think it's the problem.
It rather seems that things go wrong when I import anything but the original mov files into the first file.

Is it possible that the different file formats are the problem and is there anything I can do about it?

### Screenshots

From left to right:

1. A render of the original footage imported into blender.
2. The export from a different blend file in which the original footage was edited.
3. A render of the edited footage imported into the first blend file.

[image]

Comment: can you add screenshots to your post showing the differences?

Comment: Done. I hope that's enough to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: colorspace settings?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to? I made sure that it's sRGB for every strip. And it can't be the scene settings (in my opinion) because they are the same for all of the strips.